# Javascript Sum array of object values

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js, lodash

I would think this is a surprisingly common and simple question but I cant seem to find what Im looking for

If I had

```
var array = [{"a":4,"b":5, "d":6}, {"a":4, "c":5}, {"c":4}]
```

how do I sum the objects to get

```
{"a":8,"b":5,"c":9, "d":6}
```

using underscore, lodash, or something fairly quick and simple **one liner**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could combine [spread()](https://lodash.com/docs#spread), [merge()](https://lodash.com/docs#merge), and [add()](https://lodash.com/docs#add) to produce:

```
_.spread(_.merge)([{}].concat(array, _.add));
// → { a: 8, b: 5, d: 6, c: 13 }
```

Comment: No clue how it works but this is a brilliant solution using lodash.

Comment: Any way someone can explain how this works. I don't get how `concat` can help having the values added.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) for this

```
var compact = array.reduce(function(prev,cur){
 for(var key in cur){
  if(!cur.hasOwnProperty(key))continue;
  if(prev.hasOwnProperty(key)){
   prev[key] += cur[key];
  }else{
   prev[key] = cur[key];
  }
 }
 return prev;
},{});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer Travis. Is there a way you can see of doing this with underscore or lodash?

Comment: @Leon: Underscore has `_.reduce` if you don't want to use standard JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this solution:

```js
var arr = [{"a":4,"b":5, "d":6}, {"a":4, "c":5}, {"c":4}];
var result = {};
arr.forEach(function(obj) {
  for(var prop in obj) {
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        result[prop] = (result[prop] || 0) + obj[prop];
    }
  }
});

$('#result').text(JSON.stringify(result,null,2));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

[**`_.merge`**](https://lodash.com/docs#merge) with a custom callback would do:

```js
var array = [{"a": 4, "b": 5, "d": 6}, {"a": 4, "c": 5}, {"c": 4}];

var result = _.merge.apply(null, array.concat([function(a, b) {
  if (typeof a === 'number') {
    return a + b;
  }
}]));
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This mutates the first element of `array`, FYI.

Comment: @AdamBoduch: true. Should be solvable by injecting an empty object at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

As of lodash 4.0.0 this is simple using [mergeWith](https://lodash.com/docs#mergeWith):

_.mergeWith({}, ...array, _.add)